# Fail on spring project deployment on jboss. BeanCreationException

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, jboss

so im working on a web app that consists of couple of spring projects. To develop them and deploy locally i use eclipse neon and Jboss 6.4.

I have problem because when i try to deploy my main war on server it crashes because it cant create beans, and by that i mean it cant initialize any of them. I get the BeanCreationException.  I know for sure that code is ok, mvn clean install goes trought and some other guy i work on this with has the same code working on his machine.

I have tried Maven Update, Project clean, Reinstalling eclipse, Reinstalling jboss, Downloading code from git again, Cleaning .m2 and downloading again.
If you could tell me why it could happen that it cant create any bean in project that would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: You should show your stack trace here. Probably some configuration (spring xml or spring java config) might do well here too.

Comment: @Christian but as i said i have the exact same files from git as on the other pc but it is working there and isnt in my case, ill post stacktrace tomorrow

Comment: saying: "it works on some machine" doesn't help usually. Others need to see the stacktrace to identify what's going on on your machine. Post it here, and somebody might have an idea what's going on. As for what you told it sounds like some dependency is missing or some environment variables are not set. If you can't download a dependency for some reason, you might have such an exception. But without further logs it is impossible to tell.